# How to connect next js as frontend and codeignitor as backend, if they reside in same server

Tags: php, reactjs, apache, next.js, codeigniter-3

I am fairly new to react.

I am trying to integrate Next.js with my already existing CodeIgniter backend.

- Next.js and CodeIgniter both require its own servers(ports) to run.

So how should I configure

- Next.js to call an API on a different port.

Let's say CodeIgniter on port 80 and Next.js on 3000

With ReactJS (create-react-app) I can connect them by redirecting to index.html. Not so sure on how to go about with Next.